# How to use Awesome Print to format REST Client logs?

Tags: ruby, rest-client, awesomeprint

When using [REST Client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client) I can log calls to a text file using :

```
RestClient.log = 'log.txt'
```

Which gives useful but messy output such as:

```
RestClient.get "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all", "Accept"=>"*/*", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "User-Agent"=>"someValue"
# => 200 OK | application/json 1755 bytes
```

Is there a way to format this output using [Awesome Print](https://github.com/awesome-print/awesome_print) (or similar)?

Comment: output of response or all log ? `require awesome_print ap File.readlines('log.text')`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little bit tricky to well log Restclient but here are some tips, you need to add a formatter to the logger and also there is a [bug](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client/issues/34) with restclient, as said in the restclient doc you create a logger with:

```
[1] pry(main)> class MyLogger < Logger
  def << (msg)
    debug(msg.strip)
  end
end

[1] pry(main)* => :<<
[6] pry(main)> log = MyLogger.new('my-log.log')
=> #<MyLogger:0x007f8f2f1faf70
 @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007f8f2f1faf20 @datetime_format=nil>,
 @formatter=nil,
 @level=0,
 @logdev=
  #<Logger::LogDevice:0x007f8f2f1faed0
   @dev=#<File:my-log.log>,
   @filename="my-log.log",
   @mon_count=0,
   @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007f8f2f1fae80>,
   @mon_owner=nil,
   @shift_age=0,
   @shift_period_suffix="%Y%m%d",
   @shift_size=1048576>,
 @progname=nil>
[7] pry(main)> log.info("hola")
=> true
[8] pry(main)> require 'rest-client'
=> true
[12] pry(main)> RestClient.log = log
=> #<MyLogger:0x007f8f2f1faf70
 @default_formatter=#<Logger::Formatter:0x007f8f2f1faf20 @datetime_format=nil>,
 @formatter=nil,
 @level=0,
 @logdev=
  #<Logger::LogDevice:0x007f8f2f1faed0
   @dev=#<File:my-log.log>,
   @filename="my-log.log",
   @mon_count=0,
   @mon_mutex=#<Thread::Mutex:0x007f8f2f1fae80>,
   @mon_owner=nil,
   @shift_age=0,
   @shift_period_suffix="%Y%m%d",
   @shift_size=1048576>,
 @progname=nil>
[15] pry(main)> RestClient.get "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all", "Accept"=>"*/*", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "User-Agent"=>"someValue"
=> <RestClient::Response 200 "{\"status\":\"...">
```

with this you will get a file called my-log.log with this conent:

```
# Logfile created on 2017-09-22 13:34:11 +0200 by logger.rb/56815
I, [2017-09-22T13:34:27.270103 #17917]  INFO -- : hola
D, [2017-09-22T13:35:45.285204 #17917] DEBUG -- : RestClient.get "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all", "Accept"=>"*/*", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "User-Agent"=>"someValue"
D, [2017-09-22T13:35:45.466809 #17917] DEBUG -- : # => 200 OK | application/json 1755 bytes
```

and for another formatter:

```
[16] pry(main)> log.formatter = Proc.new{|severity, time, progname, msg|
  formatted_severity = sprintf("%-5s",severity.to_s)
  formatted_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  "My nice log: [#{formatted_severity} #{formatted_time} #{$$}] #{msg.to_s.strip}\n"
}
[19] pry(main)* => #<Proc:0x007f8f302697a8@(pry):22>
[20] pry(main)> RestClient.get "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all", "Accept"=>"*/*", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "User-Agent"=>"someValue"
```

then you will get:

```
My nice log: [DEBUG 2017-09-22 13:48:56 17917] RestClient.get "https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all", "Accept"=>"*/*", "Accept-Encoding"=>"gzip, deflate", "User-Agent"=>"someValue"
My nice log: [DEBUG 2017-09-22 13:48:56 17917] # => 200 OK | application/json 1755 bytes
```

to add awesome print, you can work as follow:
    require 'awesome_print'

```
class MyLogger < Logger
  def << (msg)
    ap(msg.strip.red) #redirect to the method added by awesome_print to Logger
  end
end
```

then after setting the logger you will get this with or without the .red:

```
D, [2017-09-23T07:41:41.702417 #5160] DEBUG -- : "RestClient.get \"https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all\", \"Accept\"=>\"*/*\", \"Accept-Encoding\"=>\"gzip, deflate\", \"User-Agent\"=>\"someValue\""
D, [2017-09-23T07:41:42.701700 #5160] DEBUG -- : "# => 200 OK | application/json 1755 bytes"
D, [2017-09-23T07:46:28.722936 #5160] DEBUG -- : "\e[1;31mRestClient.get \"https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all\", \"Accept\"=>\"*/*\", \"Accept-Encoding\"=>\"gzip, deflate\", \"User-Agent\"=>\"someValue\"\e[0m"
D, [2017-09-23T07:46:29.037056 #5160] DEBUG -- : "\e[1;31m# => 200 OK | application/json 1755 bytes\e[0m"
```

Before executing your code,
For example if it is a ruby on rails project write an initilizer called "loggerrescrlient.rb". With the following code:

```
formatter = Proc.new{|severity, time, progname, msg|
  formatted_severity = sprintf("%-5s",severity.to_s)
  formatted_time = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  "[#{formatted_severity} #{formatted_time} #{$$}] #{msg.to_s.strip}\n"
}

# Add hook for every rest-client request
RestClient.add_before_execution_proc do |req, params|

  Rails.logger.tagged("REST_to_#{req.uri.host}") do
    Rails.logger.info("HTTP request: #{req.uri}")
    Rails.logger.info("HTTP params: #{params[:payload]}")
  end
end
```

Then every time you execute the restlient will be print a log well printed
and print the response with Rails.logger.